# Use %20 instead of + while setting cookie in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

In a application I am working on , I need to set a string in the cookie, but if space is encoded as + in the cookie, and the front end is displaying as it is, how to use %20 instead of + while setting cookie.
I used response['set_cookie']="key=value", but I dont want to use this, It would be nice if i could achieve the same using cookies[:id] = value

Answer (score 1):

`%20` is the escaping character for a white space - if you meant escaping the value for setting it to the cookie.

If you want to replace it for something else, you can use `gsub`:

```
"lola+lanos".gsub("+", "%20")
# "lola%20lanos"
```